# How to pass request verification token for $.load?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, antiforgerytoken

I've to pass request verification token for $.load call, which will load respective JobSchedule action in Schedule controller. There in controller I need to decorate this JobSchedule action with [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute

```
$('#modalDialog').dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  modal: true,
  width: $(window).width(),
  open: function (event, ui) {
    $(this).load(applicationpath + "Account/Schedule/JobSchedule", selectedAccount);
  }
});
```

How can I pass the token for load?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: when you will be generating the token?

Comment: Token is generated while the view is loaded where modalDialog is present. It is in a hidden form field.
The value can be taken as shown below:
$(':input:hidden[name*="RequestVerificationToken"]').val()

Comment: where you are facing problem in this?

Comment: I want to pass the RequestVerificationToken while navigating to the action. 
Like in ajax call I'm passing :
$.ajax({
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
xhr.setRequestHeader('__RequestVerificationToken', $(':input:hidden[name*="RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
},
url: path,
type: 'GET', 
data: data,
success: function (data) {                                   
}
});

Comment: still i am not sure what you want. The code which you have posted in the comment section should work. on `open` instead of `load`, use a proper `ajax` request.

Comment: Already code in production uses $.load. I need to pass RequestVerificationToken to this.

Comment: if you are using load then you cannot send any request header with that but you can post a json data with it.

Comment: Can you pls provide a working sample how json data can be posted in $.load

Comment: you can call like `$.load('URL',{'key':'value'})`;

Comment: I've tried passing in same way. But it doesn't get passed, it throws error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65501/discussion-between-cerlin-boss-and-user3263194).

Comment: Sorry . Chat is blocked in my network.

Comment: whats the error you are getting?

Comment: What is `selectedAccount`..?

Comment: selectedAccount is a text field value. You can ignore that as well. even if I don't pass it, still it is giving me same error.